# yolo nas model not printing detected class labels

Tags: output, prediction, yolonas

I run the code it is giving labels, conf, bbboxes correctly for single input image but it is not providing that particular detected class label instead it is providing all database labels as an output.

as in colab version using for loop we were able to do predictions but in latest version we cannot iterate as it will throw error so am directly using image prediction rather running for loop. I want no of detected objects, it is providing all the class_labels that are in my datasets

```
class_names = image_prediction.class_names
labels = image_prediction.prediction.labels
confidence = image_prediction.prediction.confidence
bboxes = image_prediction.prediction.bboxes_xyxy
```